# Помогите продумать архитектуру приложения

Tags: javascript, angularjs, архитектура

Всем привет. Задумал я изучение Angular.js. Прошел пару курсов, уже некоторое время поигрался с приложением "phoneCat" из документации. Задумал простенькое приложение, которое будет собирать новости из разных источников (на выбор) и выводить на страницу.

Сейчас я пришел к следующему:

- Создал layout;

  Создал компонент "menu", который выводит меню с настройками фильтрации новостей;

  Создал компонент который выводит новость на предпросмотр.

Выглядит это примерно так:
[image]

Т.е. в лейоуте отображается меню, в меню отображается превью.

Проблема в следующем - я не знаю как правильно организовать подгрузку новостей из различных источников (скажем, из двух десятков сайтов с новостями).

Я так понимаю, что для каждого источника новости нужно создать свой сервис, который будет парсить сайт/дергать API и т.д. Это не проблема. А вот как потом работать с этими десятками сервисов, да так, чтобы это было удобно - я что-то не могу придумать.

Вопросы:

- Как работать с большим кол-вом сервисов?

  Где "правильнее" юзать эти сервисы? В контроллере компонента news-preview? В контроллере menu? Или для работы с ними лучше создать еще один сервис?

  Как блокировать/активировать сервисы? К примеру, если я хочу просматривтаь новости только из одного источника.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу ближе к классической архитектуре.

> Как работать с большим кол-вом сервисов?

Сервисы у тебя имеют одну общую характеристику - они получают список новостей. Соответсвенно для конкретной реализации сервисов можно сделать базовый класс-**адаптер**. Все конкретные сервисы - будут являться адаптерами-потомками. Для загрузки новостей потомков нужно немного - я бы обошёлся одним адаптером для получения rss - который выдают 80% новостных сайтов. Соответсвенно адаптер - это не синглтон, должна быть возможность создать несколько инстансов одного и того-же адаптера с разной конфигурацией (например с разными адресами получения rss).

Конструкцией адаптеров и оперированием с ними - по хорошему должен управлять **синглтон-фасад**, в котором например будет метод getNews(query, filter). Ибо голяком использовать адаптеры - теряется их архитектурное приемущество унифицирования.

> Где "правильнее" юзать эти сервисы?

Думаю в контроллере компонента news-preview - это же он выступает непосредственным потребителем сервиса. Само меню - является лишь фильтром.

> Как блокировать/активировать сервисы?

Фильтр по сервисам (тот что меню) - подаётся на вход в методе getNews фасада, в зависимости от фильтра фасад конструирует определённые адаптеры - и использует их в цикле.

P.S. Под термином клаcc понимается не class ES6 в JavaScript - а любой способ классификации и наследования объектов JS.

Comment: Это точно к первому ангуляру применимо?

Comment: Это применимо просто к JS, и не только - к любому языку. Нужна агрегация множества сервисов и унифицированная работа с ними: фасад+адаптеры. Если же нужны разномастные подменяемые сервисы - используем DI https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di - но это скорее не к твоей задаче.

Comment: В ангуляре, как правило, сервисы просто перечисляются в аргументах контроллера, и ангуляр создает их при первом использовании. Вы предлагаете перегрузить эту схему?

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian Ага. Обычный DI. В контексте ангулярки  - фасад для получения списка новостей - можно сделать сервисом ангуляра, а вот чем будут адаптеры и будут ли они связаны с ангуляром - вопрос реализации.